# Join together the artifacts and dependencies of several projects

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

Under a common parent I have three Maven projects that are loosely related, and I must add the jars that all of these projects generate and their dependencies to a third party ear. For each of those three projects I have properly configurate de dependency:copy-dependencies goal.

In order to have things as automated as possible, I want to join all the jars in a single location.

An initial idea would be using an empty "joiner" project that depends on all of the previous three projects, and just use dependency:copy-dependencies on it. But I do not really like the idea of an empty project with its empty artifact, and I am wondering if there is a more standard way of doing this (ideally by copying the dependencies in a directory of the parent that does not need to be commited to version control) with the standard plugins.

Comment: If you have an EAR you should use WAR/JAR dependencies in an EAR module which can handled by maven-ear-plugin no strange things via dependency-copy...etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise the EAR comes already packaged by a third party and we are (manually) adding our jars to it, I just want to have all the jars in the same place

Comment: Why adding jar's manually? Does not make sense use them as dependencies and they will be added. Otherwise you are doing something wrong.